# SQL Server LOG: "An invalid floating point operation occurred" - even though input is within range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting the error message

```
Msg 3623, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
An invalid floating point operation occurred.
```

From SQL Server 11.0.2100 (on an AWS RDS instance) for the following query:

```sql
SELECT SUM(LOG(col + 1)) FROM MyTable;
```

All values for col are within the range -0.1 and 0.1.

If I remove the SUM from the query, it runs fine, which implies the inputs to LOG are correct:

```
SELECT LOG(col + 1) FROM MyTable;
```

Also, if I select the above into a temp table, then SUM over the values in the temp table, that also works fine, which implies there's nothing wrong with the SUM:

```
SELECT LOG(col + 1) thelog INTO #x FROM MyTable;
SELECT SUM(thelog) FROM #x;
DROP TABLE #x;
```

It's only when I run SUM and LOG together that I get an issue.

Why is this happening? Is it possible that SQL Server is somehow rearranging the +1 to be outside of the LOG, so that the LOG input is out of range?

Note: Putting a CASE WHEN col > -1 inside the query also fixes it, but this shouldn't be required since all values for col + 1 are within range. I'm wondering what the underlying reason for this might be...

Comment: Is Mytable a table or a view?  Is the query really more complicated?

Comment: Just for fun, what if you try SELECT SUM(LOG(col + 1.0)) FROM MyTable;

Comment: Please add the CHECK constraint to be sure that the values are indeed in range: `ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT ck_col_within_range CHECK (col BETWEEN -0.1 AND 0.1)`

Comment: I have simulated this data and I wasn't able to reproduce your issue. The version was 11.0.3000. The query was `SELECT SUM(LOG((CONVERT(INT,CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2)))/65536.0*0.2-0.1+1)) FROM sys.all_columns, sys.all_columns a` which gave me sum of log of over 56 million of random values between -0.1 and 0.1 (+1).

Comment: Are you using a `WHERE`-clause, that you're not telling us about?

Comment: When you say "All values for col are within the range -0.1 and 0.1." I assume (as Dan does) that was probably after some `WHERE` clause had run. It is entirely possible for the calculation to get pushed down to below the filter and so run on unexpected values

Answer (score 12):

Floating point values are notorious for rounding issues because they are stored as binary fractions which often don't have an exact decimal equivalent. I think what's happening here is that one of your values is extremely close to -1 (e.g. -0.99999999999999999999), and when you add 1 it could sometimes be rounded to 0. The LOG function is undefined for an input of 0, so the result is `An invalid floating point operation occurred`.

Comment: The question specifically says "All values for col are within the range -0.1 and 0.1." so that would rule out "one of your values is extremely close to -1"

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT LOG(0) -> An invalid floating point operation occurred.

You should handle the case for the input of LOG function.
As LOG(0) is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at the article at the [database. Guide](https://database.guide/log-examples-in-sql-server/)
As per article if you have negative value passed in LOG() function the you will get

> An invalid floating point operation occurred.

[An invalid floating point operation occurred.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FLoP.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33974118)

Comment: Thanks @hemal shah! the links you referenced here helped me